# Linear Algebra Question on Equivalent Systems

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that two 2x2 homogenous systems having the same solutions are equivalent.

This is from Hoffman and Kunze where Equivalent Systems are systems where all equalities in one system are linear combinations of equalities in the other.

My attempt-

I split the problem into 3 cases of 3 different ranks:
I made an observation that for the null space to be the same (and hence the homogenous systems to have the same solution), the rank of both matrices had to be same. If it wasn't the dimension of the solutions for the two equations wouldn't be the same and hence would contradict the given data.

If the matrices are rank 0, then they are both null matrices and hence are trivially equivalent.

If both matrices are rank 2, then both of them are invertible and hence, the systems are equivalent since the row space of both spans all of $R^2$. Hence, any equality can expressed as a linear combination of the equalities of the other.

If both systems have rank 1, then I am in a confusion. That only implies that all of the four fundamental subspaces have dimension 1. How do I show that the two systems are equivalent from this?

Comment: you must look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46050/proving-that-two-systems-of-linear-equations-are-equivalent-if-they-have-the-sam?rq=1 I think it is exactly your question!