# Prove that two equations are the same if they have the same solution sets

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble understanding the logic underlying the proof for this problem (from Hefferon's *Linear Algebra*):

> Prove that, where $a, b, c, d, e$ are real numbers with $a \ne 0$, if this linear equation $ax + by = c$ has the same solution set as this one $ax + dy = e$, then they are the same equation.

The proof provided is fairly straightforward:

The solution set of the first equation is this:
$$
\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \left| x = \frac{c − by}{a} = \frac{c}{a} − \frac{b}{a} \cdot y\right.\right\} \tag{∗}
$$
Thus, given $y$, we can compute the associated $x$. Taking $y = 0$ gives the solution $(c/a, 0)$, and since the second equation $ax + dy = e$ is supposed to have the same solution set, substituting into it gives that 
$$a(c/a) + d \cdot 0 = e,$$
so $c = e$. Taking $y = 1$ in (∗) gives $$a((c − b)/a) + d · 1 = e,$$ and so $b = d$. Hence they are the same equation.

---

Why are we justified in knowing that $c = e$ in all solution sets, when we have only demonstrated it in one (when $y = 0$)? What assures us that this is the rule, and not a coincidence? I feel like this is fairly basic, so would love any help understanding what is going on here.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46050/proving-that-two-systems-of-linear-equations-are-equivalent-if-they-have-the-sam?rq=1

Comment: While not an answer to your specific remark, notice that you have two straight lines. These lines are exactly the same if they have $(x_a,y_1(x_a)=(x_a,y_2(x_a))$. All you need to do is to prove that $y_1(x_a)=y_2(x_a)$

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do my best to clear up the confusion. If something that I'm saying is not clear, please leave a comment, and I'll do my best to make it clearer.

Saying that $ax+by=c$ and $ax+dy=e$ have the same solution set is actually quite a strong statement. If $ax+by=c$ and $ax+dy=e$ have the same solution, then that means that whenever $(x,y)$ is a solution to $ax+by=c$, we automatically get that $(x,y)$ is also a solution to $ax+dy=e$, and vice versa.

Hence the argument goes like this: assume that $a\ne0$ and that $ax+by=c$ and $ax+dy=e$ have the same solution set. Since $\left(\frac{c}{a},0\right)$ is a solution to $ax+by=c$, we automatically get that $\left(\frac{c}{a},0\right)$ is also a solution to $ax+dy=e$. Hence it follows that $a\cdot\frac{c}{a}+d\cdot0=e$, which gives us that $c=e$.

Similarly, we can note that $\left(\frac{c-b}{a},1\right)$ is a solution to $ax+by=c$. Since $\left(\frac{c-b}{a},1\right)$ is a solution to $ax+by=c$, and $ax+by=c$ and $ax+dy=e$ have the same solution set, we automatically get that $\left(\frac{c-b}{a},1\right)$ is also a solution to $ax+dy=e$. Hence it follows that $a\cdot\frac{c-b}{a}+d\cdot1=e$, which gives us that $c-b+d=e$. Since we already have that $c=e$, this gives us that $b=d$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand how we can get c = e from setting y equal to 0, and substituting from there. What I don't really understand is why we can take c to be equal to e (which we have only shown to be true in the case of y=0) and assume that it is also true when y=1.

Comment: Let's forget about this problem for a moment, and let's just suppose we have real number $a$, $d$, and $e$, with $a\ne0$. The only way that $\left(\frac{c}{a},0\right)$ can be a solution to $ax+dy=e$ is if $c=e$.

Comment: If $ax+by=c$ and $ax+dy=e$ have the same solution sets, then that means we can pick points $(x,y)$ that we know are solutions to $ax+by=c$, and then use the fact that they must also be solutions to $ax+dy=e$ to figure out stuff about $d$ and $e$. The point $\left(\frac{c}{a},0\right)$ was picked because it's a solution to $ax+by=c$. But since $ax+by=c$ and $ax+dy=e$ have the same solution set, that means that $\left(\frac{c}{a},0\right)$ must also be a solution to $ax+dy=e$. And the only way for $\left(\frac{c}{a},0\right)$ to be a solution to $ax+dy=e$ is if $c=e$.

Comment: Ahh I think that framing cleared everything up. It's not a matter of a certain variable equaling another in a single random instance, and extrapolating that instance to others, it's that without those variables being equal, the instance would not be possible at all.

Comment: Awesome! If you have more questions, let me know. I'll be happy to help!

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: My pleasure! Thanks for posting your question!